# Node.js express res.json behavior

Tags: json, node.js, angular, http

I have been working on one of my projects using `node` and `ng4`

when I came across using `res.json` to send an array back to Angular 4 front end, like `res.json(arrayResult)`. Surprisingly, I cannot use `JSON.parse(arrayResult)` after Angular receives it because it throws an error saying unexpected end of input. I however can access all the data through result[i], just like any normal array.

I don't quite understand why `res.json()` does not send my array as a string to the front end. Is there any internal conversion involved? Why I could access the content through index without even parsing it or doing any conversion with it?

Comment: `res.json` is setting the `content-type` of the response to `application/json`: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L264

Comment: `res.json()` does send your content as a JSON string (with appropriate content-type) - that's how it works.  If you look at that request/response in the network tab in the Chrome browser, you can see exactly what is being sent across the wire. Probably Angular is already parsing it for you so it's already a Javascript object and thus you can't reparse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server indeed send your json data as a string. Additionally to the string, the server passes `Content-Type` header to your client which tells your client what kind of data you received.

So if the `Content-Type` was `text/html` your client would think that he received an HTML file.

In your case, res.json using `Content-Type: application/json` which tells the client that the string that he got is actually a json object, so no need for you to use `JSON.parse`.

You can see the `Content-Type` under the response `headers` property.